# How do I cast Any returned from executeInsert in Anorm to Long

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1, anorm

In my Scala Playframework app I'm trying to, with `executeInsert`, create a sms_token(class). 
Then with the primary key create a unique token, add it to sms_token and save it with `executeUpdate`.

```
case class SmsToken(id: Option[Long], token: String, phoneNumber: String, startDate: Option[Date], endDate: Option[Date], used: Boolean, tempReviewGrade: Option[Int], tempReviewText: Option[String])

object SmsToken {
  val simple = {
    get[Option[Long]]("id") ~
      get[String]("token") ~
      get[String]("phone_number") ~
      get[Option[Date]]("start_date") ~
      get[Option[Date]]("end_date") ~
      get[Boolean]("used") ~
      get[Option[Int]]("temp_review_grade") ~
      get[Option[String]]("temp_review_text") map {
      case id ~ token ~ phone_number ~ start_date ~ end_date ~ used ~ temp_review_grade ~ temp_review_text => SmsToken(id, token, phone_number, start_date, end_date, used, temp_review_grade, temp_review_text)
    }
  }
}
```

method:

```
 def createToken(n: String): Option[Long] = {

    var addedTokenPk = 0L

    val result = DB.withConnection {
      implicit connection =>
        SQL("insert into sms_token(token, phone_number, start_date, end_date, used, temp_review_grade, temp_review_text) values({token},{phone_number},{start_date},{end_date},{used}, {temp_review_grade}, {temp_review_text})").on(
          'token -> "",
          'phone_number -> n,
          'start_date -> new Date(),
          'end_date -> new Date(),
          'used -> 0,
          'temp_review_grade -> 0,
          'temp_review_text -> ""
        ).executeInsert()
    }
    result match {
      case Some(pk) => {
        addedTokenPk = pk.asInstanceOf[Long]
      }
      case None => println("YAAARRRRR")
    }

    if (addedTokenPk != 0L) {

      val token = Util.createUniqueToken(addedTokenPk)

      DB.withConnection {
        implicit connection =>
          SQL("update sms_token s set s.token={token} where s.id={id}").on(
            'id -> ("" + addedTokenPk).toLong,
            'token -> token
          ).executeUpdate()
      }
      return Some(addedTokenPk)
    }
    None
  }
```

my question is regarding this part:

```
result match {
    case Some(pk) => {
        addedTokenPk = pk.asInstanceOf[Long]
    }
    case None => println("YAAARRRRR")
}
```

executeInsert returns an Any object and since the key is Long I'm doing `asInstanceOf[Long]` 
since I need it later in the update part. I'm a Scala noob so I'm not sure that this is correct.. Maybe there is some better Scala way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You get the Long id if you invoke `map` on the `executeInsert` result

```
DB.withConnection { implicit connection =>
   SQL("...").executeInsert().map(id => println(id))
}
```

Comment: hmm my executeInsert() doesn't have the method .map . I guess I'm missing something?

Comment: `executeInsert()` returns an Option[Long] and Option has a `map` method

Comment: I just noticed that your parser looks weird: `get[Option[Long]]("id")` should be `get[Pk[Long]]("id")` maybe that makes the difference.

Comment: Which libraries are you using? I'm using import anorm._
import anorm.SqlParser._
import anorm.~
import play.api.db._
and if i check the method : def executeInsert[A](generatedKeysParser : anorm.ResultSetParser[A] = { /* compiled code */ })(implicit connection : java.sql.Connection) : A = { /* compiled code */ }

Comment: The method signature of the `executeInsert()` method I call is equal to yours. Another difference is that I usually use a sequence to let the database generate the next id and use `nextval` in my queries

Comment: In the play samples they have a different approach: [link](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1.x/samples/scala/zentasks/app/models/Project.scala) see the `create` method

Comment: It must be my Intellij IDEA that is crazy...It works with your example.... This is very strange

Comment: Indeed, IDEA is crazy on this one http://d.pr/i/zT7A, I reported the issue on Jetbrains Youtrack: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-6007

Comment: You can fix the Intellij complaint by specifying the Option return type in executeInsert: `SQL("...").executeInsert[Option[Long]]().map(id => println(id))`

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to pass the `simple` parser to executeInsert:

```
val result: SmsToken = DB.withConnection {
  implicit connection =>
    SQL("insert into sms_token(token, phone_number, start_date, end_date, used, temp_review_grade, temp_review_text) values({token},{phone_number},{start_date},{end_date},{used}, {temp_review_grade}, {temp_review_text})").on(
      'token -> "",
      'phone_number -> n,
      'start_date -> new Date(),
      'end_date -> new Date(),
      'used -> 0,
      'temp_review_grade -> 0,
      'temp_review_text -> ""
    ).executeInsert(simple.single)
}
```

This often allows you to do the above in one pass, and in this case you'll have access to pk and the token allowing you to reference `result` attributes in the database query.

*Note: I was searching to try and do exactly this and stumbled on this question.*